# How to change substring in url and redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to load my page always in that way:

```
http://myhost/options=mymodule

or:

http://myhost/options=mymodule?(...) something
```

but the system also has other modules:

```
http://myhost/options=othermodule

or

http://myhost/options=othermodule?(...) something
```

I want always redirect to my module. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

in a htaccess file or in your apache configuration file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /options=othermodule(.*) /options=mymodule$1
```

Comment: Nips: do you want everything to be redirected to mymodule?

Comment: Yes, I would like to redirected each page to my module

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)options=mymodule(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?options=mymodule [L]
```